# How to solve parsing error for event.preventDefault when creating a button

Tags: reactjs, forms, event-handling

I am new to React and struggling to create a login button. I get the following error:
./src/Form.js
Line 22:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

20 |       };
21 |

> 22 |       event.preventDefault;
> |            ^
> 23 |
> 24 |   render() {
> 25 |     return (

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classes from './Form.module.css';

class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: ''
    };
  }

  handleUsernameChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      username: event.target.value
    });
  };

  handleLoginChange = (event) => {
    alert('${this.state.username} ');
      };
      
      event.preventDefault;

  render() {
    return (
      <form className={classes.Form} on Login = {this.handleLogin}>
      
        <label>Username</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.username}
          onChange={this.handleUsernameChange}
        ></input>
        <button type="login">Login</button>
      
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your event.preventDefault() inside the function you want to use it for (notice that you need to call the function through parenthesis).

Also note to use backticks **`** when using javascript elements inside of a string should you choose to use a string-based implementation.

```
handleLoginChange = (event) => {
     event.preventDefault()
     alert(`${this.state.username}`)
     }
```

Once you get classes down, definitely look into using hooks and functional components in the future (with a few exceptions).

Comment: Thank you it works now...will try use hooks such as useState with functions in future

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `preventDefault` is a function, so you should add `()` at the end. Then if you can notice, is outside the handleLoginChange function.

Try this:

```
handleLoginChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('${this.state.username} ');
      };
```

Comment: Hi Ali, I copied and pasted your code but still get the following error:

./src/Form.js
  Line 23:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  21 |       };
  22 |       
> 23 |       event.preventDefault;
     |            ^
  24 |
  25 |   render() {
  26 |     return (

Answer (score 0):

So, `preventDefault()` is a function and you had placed it outside of every function in your code.

Then `On Login` is not correct, it would be correct to use `onSubmit` and connect a function to handle the submit.

In the end, you have to bind your event handlers to correct context (this).

The correct way to do what you want is this:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: ""
    };
  }

  handleUsernameChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      username: event.target.value
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(`${this.state.username}`);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.username}
          onChange={this.handleUsernameChange.bind(this)}
        ></input>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

If the solution works, tick as the correct answer.

**useful resources**:
https://it.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html